# Android: change array value from other class

Tags: java, android, variables

i've two class.
the first class is

```
public class A{

    private static int[] x = {0,0,0,0};
    private static int justX = 0;

    public A(){}

    public static int[] getX(){return x;}
    public static int getJustX(){ return justX;}
}
```

and the second class is

```
public class B extends . . .{
    private int[] x;
    private justX;

    public B(){
        x = A.getX(); 
        justX = A.getJustX();
        Log.d("X: ", Arrays.toString(x)); //X: {0,0,0,0}
        Log.d("JUST X: ", String.value(justX)); //JUST X: 0;
    }

    private void onTouch(){
        x[0] = 1;
        x[1] = 1;
        x[2] = 1;
        x[3] = 1;
        justX = 1;

        Log.d("X: ",Arrays.toString(A.getX())); //X: {1,1,1,1}
        Log.d("JUST X: ", String.value(A.getJustX())); //JUST X: 0;
    }
}
```

array variable from class A changed but integer variable has not changed, Why did it happen?

Comment: Java objects use value pointer to keep reference with it's objects. So A.x and B.x points to the same value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're encountering is that Java is always pass-by-value for primitive types (like `int`), but for object types, it's a little more complicated (and arrays are objects). Specifically, what happens is that assigning to a variable with a reference type changes what object it refers to, but doesn't create a new object. Assigning to a primitive variable just changes the value of that variable.

Let's walk through things.

```
public class B extends . . .{
    private int[] x;
    private justX;

    public B(){
        x = A.getX();
```

At this point, you've made `B.x` into a reference to the same array that `A.x` is a reference to. So they're both names for the same data structure.

```
        justX = A.getJustX();
```

And here `justX` just got the value that `A.justX` had (0).

```
        Log.d("X: ", Arrays.toString(x)); //X: {0,0,0,0}
        Log.d("JUST X: ", String.value(justX)); //JUST X: 0;
    }

    private void onTouch(){
        x[0] = 1;
        x[1] = 1;
        x[2] = 1;
        x[3] = 1;
```

Here, you've reached inside `B.x`, and changed the values of parts inside it. But it's the same object that `A.x` also refers to, so when you look at `A.x`, you'll see those same changes.

```
        justX = 1;
```

And here you're just taking `B.justX` and giving it a new value.

```
        Log.d("X: ",Arrays.toString(A.getX())); //X: {1,1,1,1}
        Log.d("JUST X: ", String.value(A.getJustX())); //JUST X: 0;
    }
}
```

Hopefully that explains why you're getting the result you're getting. If you want to change `A.justX`, you'll need to do so explicitly. If you want to be able to change `B.x` without also changing `A.x`, then you'll need to explicitly make a new object (for instance, with `.clone()`).

Comment: Yeah, its solved my question. I just found out about it, coz i learned java not from the beginning. before i know about `clone()` i just set `B.x` using looping from `int[] tmp = A.getX()` and set `B.x`. Thank Adam.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are changing the copy of the array. Once you are done changing the array and justX, you have to set it again.

```
public class A{

    private static int[] x = {0,0,0,0};
    private static int justX = 0;

    public A(){}

    public static int[] getX(){return x;}
    public static int getJustX(){ return justX;}
    public static void setX(int[] a){x = a;};
    public static void setJustX(int j){justX = j;}
}
```

and

```
public class B extends . . .{
    private int[] x = A.getX();
    private justX = A.get;

    public B(){
        x = A.getX(); 
        justX = A.getJustX();
        Log.d("X: ", Arrays.toString(x)); //X: {0,0,0,0}
        Log.d("JUST X: ", String.value(justX)); //JUST X: 0;
    }

    private void onTouch(){
        x[0] = 1;
        x[1] = 1;
        x[2] = 1;
        x[3] = 1;
        justX = 1;
        A.setX(x);
        A.setJustX(justX);

        Log.d("X: ",Arrays.toString(A.getX())); //X: {1,1,1,1}
        Log.d("JUST X: ", String.value(A.getJustX())); //JUST X: 0;
    }
}
```